# Unknown:generic Error When deploying firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have very simple cloud function truggers firestore document `onCreate`, when i deploy this function I'm getting Error

```
Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        makeUppercase
```

In cloud logs

```
ERROR: error fetching storage source: generic::unknown: retry budget exhausted (3 attempts): fetching gcs source: unpacking source from gcs: source fetch container exited with non-zero status: 1
```

My function .ts

import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.firestore.document("/clients/{documentId}")
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      // Grab the current value of what was written to Firestore.
      const original = snap.data().original;
      functions.logger.log("Uppercasing", context.params.documentId, original);
      const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
      return snap.ref.set({uppercase}, {merge: true});
    });
```

Also please check my [firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N30gb.png)

In package JSON node version is 14. I don't know what went wrong, I have been trying this couple of hours and always same Error.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't enabled various permissions yet.  You have to explicitly add various account privileges in your GCloud to access things like the gcs (where the deployable containers are stored) - I would put as an answer, but I don't have the details for which permissions, exactly, available at the moment.

Comment: Try deploying again with --verbostiy=debug and --log-http flags it will show more information and probably the cause of the issue. If you want you can share it with me and I can take a look at it.